# Как кодом из php вывести переменную в HTML

Tags: php

Есть такой PHP

```php
function setInterval($func, $milliseconds)
{
    $second = (int)$milliseconds / 1000;
    while(true)
    {
        $func();
        sleep($second);
    }
}

$startTime = 100;
function update()
{
    $startTime += 12;
    // Сделать вывод переменной $startTime в HTML элемент с id='cout' 
}
setInterval(update(), 1000);
require_once 'index.php'
```

и такой HTML

```html
<div id="cout"></div>
```

Я хочу сделать то, что делает `innerHTML` из JS.

Comment: Смешались в кучу кони, люди... Из php обновлять значения на html странице клиента нельзя. Можно с помощью js через ajax, websocket, long polling получать данные от php скрипта

Comment: Сие надо на js писать.

Comment: @Kirill да, буду изменять значение в файле с помощью php потом считывать его с помощью js и выводить в html

Comment: <div id="cout"><?=$variable?></div>

Comment: ага, такое только через JS, php это серверный язык, т.е. выполняет код только один раз по запросу на страницу, если это необходимо важно что бы он запускался на сервере, необходимо использовать ajax,можно еще веб сокеты но это уже лишнее